# How to read XCode Instruments' profile tree view?

Tags: xcode, profiling, instruments

I am trying to get myself used to XCode instruments to profile my code. I happen to see this tree view in Instruments' time profiler:

[image]

What irritates me is the following: The highlighted function `HeapMatrix::pivot` is not called from `main` directly, but only from others (e.g., `GradedMatrix::kernel`). So, do I have to read this as: all calls to `HeapMatrix::pivot`, be it directly from the function `main` *or indirectly from the functions called by `main`*, add up to 10.31s?

Answer (score 0):

The Weight column tells you the amount of time the function was on the call stack. Your listing says that `HeapMatrix::pivot` was on the call stack for 10.31 seconds, which doesn't tell you much.

When profiling with the Time Profiler instrument, the Self Weight column is more important. The Self Weight column tells you how long the function was at the top of the call stack. Functions with a high value in the Self Weight column are the ones you should look to optimize.

The following article covers the Time Profiler instrument in more detail:

[Finding the Slow Spots in Your Code with the Time Profiler Instrument](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/finding-the-slow-spots-in-your-code-with-the-time-profiler-instrument/)

Comment: But what does the tree view mean? I would have thought that I should read the screenshot as: for 1:20m, `main` was on the call stack, and for 10.31s, `HeapMatrix::pivot` was on the stack *right below*, which must be wrong, as `main` never calls `pivot` directly. Also, I see multiple copies of `pivot` directly under main, which I also struggle to interpret. What does that mean?

Comment: I don't know why `HeapMatrix::pivot` is directly under `main` in the call tree view. Apple doesn't provide much documentation on how they show functions in the call tree view. Looking at your screenshot, it appears Instruments sorts the functions under `main` by the Weight column. But the screenshot shows only two functions so I can only guess.